# Expose VPN connection on network

Tags: linux, windows, networking, vpn

connect to my work network from my home desktop through a VPN connection.

What I am trying to achieve is expose this connection on to my mobile (Android) which connects to internet through 3G network. The original VPN vendor in use by my company does not have a mobile client.

I guess, I need to setup a VPN server(such as OpenVPN having mobile client) on my desktop which will expose the connected VPN network to my work.

Can anyone tell me pointers on how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please be aware that by doing this, you might be violating quite a few company policies as you are exposing the internal network using a non-sanctioned authentication method and a VPN protocol that may have different security settings as your company VPN. Please do talk to your IT department before doing any of this.

Now, to achieve this, you will need to expose at least one port of your home computer to the internet. If you are behind a router, you will need to configure that.

I also assume, you have a *dynamic IP address*, so you will need to set up an account with DynDNS or one of it's clones.

As a final step, you need to pick a VPN client. Since it's a company VPN, I suggest either L2TP or OpenVPN, both should be sufficiently secure. There are a ton of tutorials out there. Since all your mobile's internet traffic will end up on your home computer, the home computer's routing decisions will affect that as well, so your company traffic should go to the company VPN.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am just doing it to learn aspects of network security and don't intend to use it in actual. Based on my experience, what I have seen is whenever VPN gets activated, it will not allow access to original LAN network, which will make opening the port to Internet difficult if not impossible. I will try anyways, thanks.

Comment: It is possible your company VPN is routing everything through the VPN. If you want access to your local network, you need to add a more specific route. For more details see the `ip route` command on Linux or the `route` command on Windows.